# How to call a function repeatedly until a condition is met and collect the results in a list, in a single statement without a while loop

Tags: python, loops

I am writing a program and I have this line of code:

```
self.languages = [while ans != 'no': ans = input('Insert a language you know: ')]
```

I hope to achieve this interaction:

```
Insert a language you know: English
Insert a language you know: French
Insert a language you know: no
```

and then `self.languages` will be `['English', 'French']`.

But when I execute it this is the output:

```
self.languages = [while ans != 'no': ans = input('Insert a language you know: ')]
                 ^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also tried this:

```
self.languages = while ans != 'no': ans = input('Insert a language you know: ')
```

but it gives the same error.

What can I do?

Comment: `while` is a statement, you can't use it in an expression or assign it to anything.

Comment: @Michael Butscher yes, i meant that but doesn't it work  also for if

Comment: `if` can be part of the list comprehension. You should work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no syntax similar to list comprehensions that uses `while` instead of `for`.

However, you can use [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) in its two-argument form:

- The first argument is a callable `f` that is executed repeatedly.
- The second argument is a sentinel value that stops the iteration if `f` returns it.
- The results of the iteration (the return values of `f` before the sentinel) are collected using the `list()` constructor.

```
list(iter(lambda: input('Insert a language you know: '), 'no'))
```